# Appium no longer finds elements on iOS 13.3 Safari

Tags: c#, selenium, appium, ios13

I seem to be having trouble with running my scripts on a real iOS device.

I have an iPhone 6 on iOS 12.4.3 and my scripts run fine on it.
I have an iPhone 7 on iOS 13.3 and it is unable to find any element on the webpage.

I can open a webpage on both devices, the iPhone 6 can find an element on the page and click on it, but the iPhone 7 cannot see the element, the Test Results output says the driver.FindElement() function times out after 60 seconds.

I'm using Selenium.Webdriver 3.12.1 and Appium.Webdriver 3.0.0.2
I've tried updating selenium but I can't update appium, it's giving me an error but that's different problem.

Was there a change in iOS13 or something else that could be causing this time out? Is it fixable or do I need to update the Webdrivers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure the elements are the same? I have seen some funky stuff happen where on one phone the ID for something is `element` and on another its `Element` with a capital letter but it would be helpful if you could post some screenshots or the code leading up to the failure

Comment: We are facing the same issue but using Java. @Swats have you found any solution working?

Comment: The elements are definitely the same. Here is some of the logs from Appium
`code`
    [RemoteDebugger] Executing atom 'find_element'

    [RemoteDebugger] Executing 'find_element' atom in default context

    [RemoteDebugger] Sending javascript command: '(function(){return function() 
    {var k=this;functi...'

    [W3C (4035d106)] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Did not 
    get any response after 300s
`code`
The phone will sit there with the website open and nothing will happen, and it waits for ages before it fails.